# Is it faster to load packages together or not?

Tags: packages

I would like to know that which one of the following commands is faster in running?

‎`‎\usepackage{A,B,C,...}‎` or

```
‎\usepackage{A}‎
‎\usepackage{B}‎
‎\usepackage{C}‎
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In either case, the difference is too small to worry about it. If you preamble is slow to process, you might consider using [mylatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/mylatex) to speed things up.

Comment: As Will says, the difference will be pretty small as most of the processing will be in the packages themselves.

Comment: +1 for the useful suggestion. I've never heard of mylatex.

Answer (score 5):

I think the only difference that may arise is when you have to specify some options for the packages you are loading. In this case you have to load the packages one by one.

Comment: (*) unless by design or coincidence, they both accept the same options you intend to pass (e.g., `\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor,graphicx}`).

Comment: Or if it's likely that at some stage you might want to comment out one or other of the packages, keeping the packages separate is a good idea...